# Sort list by a given custom order

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples

```
x = [('U', 3), ('R', 3)]
```

I want to sort the list by a custom order for the first element of every tuple ('U', or 'R')

The order should be:

```
order = ["R", "D", "L", "U"]
```

so the **output** of my example would be:

```
x = [('R', 3), ('U', 3)]
```

how can I do that in optimal time?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sorted(x, key=lambda x: order.index(x[0]))
```

`index()` will return a proper comparable key (first element of tuple)

Comment: Take care that if the value is not in the list will throw an exception

Answer (score 4):

If the inputs are large, it's worth precalculating a dictionary for quick element position lookup:

```
order_map = {}
for pos, item in enumerate(order):
    order_map[item] = pos

sorted(x, key=lambda x: order_map[x[0]])
```