# How to sort a list of strings with a different order?

Tags: python, list, sorting, character

I am writing a function in Python which can sort my list. The problem is that I don't want it in the same order that the `sorted()` method used. I tried using the `sorting()` method, but when I sort this string, which I it comes out like this:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzßàáäåæçèéêìíîñòóôöøùúüžα
```

The order I want it to be in is:

```
0123456789aàáäåæbcçdeèéêfghiìíîjklmnñoòóôöøpqrsßtuùúüvwxyzžα
```

Now, I've got a list like this (example):

```
list = ['x', 'h', 'ê', 'ø', '5', 'ž', 'z', 'α', '3', '1']
```

And I want so sort it. If I'd use the `sorted()` method, it would look like this:

```
['1', '3', '5', 'h', 'x', 'z', 'ê', 'ø', 'ž', 'α']
```

But I want it to be in the same order as the string I gave before.

Comment: See the [python tutorial on sorting](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions), especially the second on `key` functions.  You want something like `key = lambda s: reference.index(s)` where reference is the string you've listed above with the proper sorting order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort list by a given custom order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900759/sort-list-by-a-given-custom-order)

Comment: The first part of your answer lies in the `key` parameter to [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).  The second part is to describe that key function.  The obvious way is a hard-coded `dict` mapping all of the variants of "a" to just `'a'`.  Coming up with that on your own might be hard, because there are a _lot_ of Unicode characters that are some variant of an ASCII letter like "a".  (Does "a with combining vector arrow" count?)  Such a function might already be available in a library somewhere.

Comment: Is that a complete list of the characters you want to sort, or do you have to handle _any_ "Roman-like" Unicode character?  That would include weirdos like "MODIFIER LETTER SMALL W" ([U+02B7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02b7/)), "BLACK-LETTER CAPITAL Z" ([U+2128](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2128/)), and "DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL C" ([U+2102](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2102/)), to name just a few.

Comment: no. these are the only characters I need to use!

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I don't see how there are two "parts" to the question.  The question is how to implement a custom sort order (based on the location of each object to be sorted in a string provided).  I chose my duplicate because the question essentially is sort based on a custom order (based on location in a list provided), abstractly the same question and the solution there could be used in this case with minimal modification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is to associate to each char the index in the specified order and use the indexes of the string chars to do the order comparison.

**Note**: only works with Python 3

**Sort one char strings**

```
ORDER = "0123456789aàáäåæbcçdeèéêfghiìíîjklmnñoòóôöøpqrsßtuùúüvwxyzžα"
# associate each char with the index in the string
# this makes sort faster for multiple invocations when compared with
# ORDER.index(c)
POS = {c:p for (p, c) in enumerate(ORDER)}

lst = ['x', 'h', 'ê', 'ø', '5', 'ž', 'z', 'α', '3', '1']

lst.sort(key = lambda c: POS[c])
# or, suggested by wim
lst.sort(key = POS.get)
```

**Sort any length strings**

```
class MyStrOrder:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __lt__(self, other):
        for i in range(min(len(self.inner), len(other.inner))):
            a = POS.get(self.inner[i])
            b = POS.get(other.inner[i])
            if a != b:
                return a < b
        return len(self.inner) < len(other.inner)

lst = ["abc", "ab", "aá"]
lst.sort()
print(lst)

lst = ["abc", "ab", "aá"]
lst.sort(key = MyStrOrder)
print(lst)
```

Outputs:

```
['ab', 'abc', 'aá']
['aá', 'ab', 'abc']
```

Comment: @wim That's a great suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: This works great for single-character strings. I don't know if that's sufficient for the OP, but the answer would be much more useful for the ages if you could generalize it to arbitrary length strings.

Comment: @MarkRansom I update the answers. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There's a small bug in `__lt__`, it fails when one string is a subset of the other. You can fix it by replacing `return False` with `return len(a) < len(b)`. And someone should mention that this is Python 3 where strings are Unicode by default.

Comment: I see you fixed the answer, and also deciphered my intent rather than my mistaken instructions. Well done!