# How to assign a variable to a number to sort

Tags: python

I've just found out about the sort option in Python and have been trying to get it to order variables.  Is there a way to give them a value like a number to do a sort?

```
b1 = "bronze 1"
b2 = "bronze 2"
b3 = "bronze 3"
s1 = "silver 1"
s2 = "silver 2"
s3 = "silver 3"
g1 = "gold 1"
g2 = "gold 2"
g3 = "gold 3"
# they are in order above

print(sorted({b2, b3, b1, s1, s2, s3, g1, g2, g3}))
```

I want it to tell me which ranks are in order. How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly did you expect to be the output of this program?

Comment: bronze 1, bronze 2, bronze 3, silver 1, silver 2, silver 3, gold 1, gold 2, gold 3 Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of strings with a different order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355466/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-with-a-different-order)

Comment: In your case, `ORDER = [b1, b2, b3, s1, s2, s3, g1, g2, g3]` when using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355570).

Comment: Is it better to be a string?

Comment: sry the post didnt rlly answer my question

Comment: I got an error running it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the positional argument `key` to the `sorted()` function for customized sorting.

```py
>>> unsorted = ['bronze 2', 'gold 1', 'gold 2', 'bronze 1', 'silver 2', 'silver 1', 'gold 3', 'silver 3', 'bronze 3']
>>> def sort_list(_list):
        sorted_list = []
        sort_key = lambda s: int(s[-1])
        for string in ["bronze", "silver", "gold"]:
            sublist = [i for i in _list if string in i]
            sorted_list.extend(sorted(sublist, key=sort_key))
        return sorted_list

>>> sort_list(unsorted)
['bronze 1', 'bronze 2', 'bronze 3', 'silver 1', 'silver 2', 'silver 3', 'gold 1', 'gold 2', 'gold 3']
```

If desired, this can be simplified using list comprehension:

```py
>>> def sort_list(_list):
    sorted_list = []
    for string in ["bronze", "silver", "gold"]:
        sorted_list.extend(
            sorted([i for i in _list if string in i], key=lambda s: int(s[-1]))
        )
    return sorted_list

>>> sort_list(unsorted)
['bronze 1', 'bronze 2', 'bronze 3', 'silver 1', 'silver 2', 'silver 3', 'gold 1', 'gold 2', 'gold 3']
```

Comment: sry for the dumb question but how can I tell if it works?

Comment: @Pricysquirrl by comparing the output you get with the output you want

Comment: sry 1 last thing.  When printing sort_list(unsorted) I get square brackets around the output.  How do I get rid of those

Comment: If you want to iterate through the list and print each item, you can use a `for` loop: `for i in sort_list(unsorted):`, then on the next block, `print(i)`.