# Custom Sort a Grouped Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, sorting

This is my toy data set:

```
data_test= {'date':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4, 4 ], 
'cid':[99, 99, 99, 99,  99,99,99,99,99,100,100,  99,99 , 100, 100, 100, 100], 
'page':['page1', 'page2', 'page1', 'page2', 'page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page3', 'page4','page6', 'page6', 'page7', 'page8', 'page9' ,'page10'], 
'campaignset':['c1','c1','c1','c1', 'c1', 'c2','c2','c2','c1','c1','c2','c1', 'c1','c1', 'c2','c2', 'c2']} 

data_test_df = pd.DataFrame(data_test)
data_drop_dups = data_test_df.drop_duplicates(['campaignset', 'date', 'page', 'cid'])
data_grouped = data_drop_dups.groupby(['campaignset', 'date', 'page']).cid.size()
data_grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(data_grouped)
```

This (data_grouped_df) is what it looks like after writing to csv:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I want a custom sort that will put things like 'page10' to the 'sensible' sequential position, after page 9, or page 8, or page 5, whatever comes immediately before it. My production code does not have numbers at the end. And it is not in alphanumeric order logically. So production code's page var would have an order like ['apple', 'cat', 'igloo', 'banana'....] That is why I created sortlist below as one of the things I tried on this toy dataset.

```
sortlist = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page6', 'page7', 'page8', 'page8', 'page9', 'page10']
sorted(data_grouped_df['page'],key = sortlist)
```

It gave me an error:

```
KeyError: 'page'
```

I also tried this:

```
sorted(data_grouped_df['page'], key=lambda data_grouped_df['page']: sortlist))
```

going off of this post: [Sort list by a given custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900759/sort-list-by-a-given-custom-order/33900835)

It also gave me an error:

```
sorted(data_grouped_df['page'], key=lambda data_grouped_df['page']: sortlist))
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any insights?

Thanks!

Update:

I tried this as per advice below, but it's not working for me. Although I **think** what I really need is to use sortlist, not str.extr() because my production code's var has correct order in non-alphanumeric.

```
df  = data_grouped_df.assign(key=data_grouped_df["page"].str.extract("(\d+)").astype(int))\
    .sort_values(
      ["campaignset", "date", "key"].drop("key", axis=1))
```

Comment: Why all those dataframes? Which one should we assume you want to work from? Also it doesn't quite look like that, its a multiIndex dataframe

Comment: I want to work from data_grouped_df. When you output it to a csv, it does look like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
data_grouped_df = data_grouped_df.reset_index()

df  = data_grouped_df.assign(key=data_grouped_df["page"].str.extract("(\d+)").astype(int))\
    .sort_values(
      ["campaignset", "date", "key"].drop("key", axis=1)


print(df)

   campaignset  date    page  cid
0           c1     1   page1    1
1           c1     1   page2    1
2           c1     2   page1    1
3           c1     2   page3    1
4           c1     2   page5    1
5           c1     3   page6    1
6           c1     4   page7    1
7           c2     2   page2    1
8           c2     2   page3    1
9           c2     2   page4    2
11          c2     4   page8    1
12          c2     4   page9    1
10          c2     4  page10    1
```

or using `pd.Categorical`

```
sortlist = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page6', 'page7', 'page8', 'page9', 'page10']

data_grouped_df = data_grouped_df.reset_index()

data_grouped_df['page'] = pd.Categorical(data_grouped_df['page'],categories=sortlist)

df = data_grouped_df.sort_values(['campaignset','date','page'])

print(df)

   campaignset  date    page  cid
0           c1     1   page1    1
1           c1     1   page2    1
2           c1     2   page1    1
3           c1     2   page3    1
4           c1     2   page5    1
5           c1     3   page6    1
6           c1     4   page7    1
7           c2     2   page2    1
8           c2     2   page3    1
9           c2     2   page4    2
11          c2     4   page8    1
12          c2     4   page9    1
10          c2     4  page10    1
```

Comment: Thanks Datanovice!! Glad it's working for you!! But it's throwing me Key Errror: Page again. I updated my post with additional comments.

Comment: Also, I probably didn't give a very good example with the page names. What my production code has is not numbers at the end. The structure is all string, and it is a-z or z-a in logic. So that's why I had the sortlist.

Comment: @Divs its working as per your example, but see edit to handle your request.